# Проверять наличие питона на Windows, если нет, то устанавливать

Tags: python, windows, bat

Возможно ли создать какой-нибудь `.bat`, чтобы при его запуске, он проверял, есть ли на машине с Windows питон, и если нет, то устанавливал?

Если есть способ, то куда мне смотреть и с чего начинать?

Или может есть другие способы, помимо `.bat`?

Comment: А вам для какой цели это нужно? -_-

Comment: @DGDays Нужно развернуть Sysmon на всех машинах в организации, мб есть способ без питона качать сразу Sysmon, ну вот что-то не нагуглил :(

Comment: Такс, а дайте ссылку как вы устанавливаете его? Просто не могу найти информацию по этому -_-

Comment: Ты щас рассказываешь про задачи систем управления конфигурацией и\или про GPO.